# Layout not moving up when keyboard is open in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a layout in Jetpack Compose where I have a couple of composables (text view and input) that I need to stay at the top of the screen, and then another composable (button) that I need to stay attached to the bottom of the screen. When the keyboard is opened to type into the text input, I need the button attached to the bottom of the screen to move up with it, however this isn't happening.

```
ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .statusBarsPadding()
            .padding(0.dp, 32.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)
            .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),

    ) {
        Column {
            
            CustomHeading6(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 32.dp),
                title = "Enter Email"
            )

            CustomBody1(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 12.dp),
                content = "Email:"
            )

            CustomEmailTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 20.dp),
                text = viewModel.emailAddress,
                onValueChanged = { //removed }
            )
        }

        Column {
            CustomButton(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 32.dp),
                title = "Submit",
                onButtonClick = { //removed }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to achieve the attach to top/bottom by wrapping each set of items in their own columns and then using Arrangement.SpaceBetween on the wrapper column, but perhaps this isn't correct. I also tried without this and instead adding .weight(1f) to the column with the composables attached to the top. Neither of these allowed the layout to move up with the keyboard.

I also have this in the main activity:

```
 WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    setContent {
        ProvideWindowInsets {
            Theme {
                      // my content
            }
         }
     }
```

and this in the manifest for my activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Note that you can use named arguments, which is much easier to read and doesn't require specifying all parameters, which have default value. E.g. `Modifier.padding(bottom = 32.dp)` instead of `Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 32.dp)`

Comment: Most probably your modifier works fine, but because of `verticalScroll` it looks the same, as scroll position is not changed. You need to manually scroll to the focused view. Generally, it's [one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120) of the most starred compose issues.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Oh thanks for the tip! I didn't realise this

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Ah okay, so is it not possible to make the button stuck to the bottom of the screen instead stick to the top of the keyboard when it is open when in a scroll view? I don't really want to take out the scroll incase of small screen size, but equally would like everything to be visible without scroll if the screen space allows.